# using xquery how to loop thru characters in a string and remove leading zeros

Tags: osb

I have a requirement to remove leading zeros from a string value.

Example:

- 00012MD78009850 should become: 12MD78009850
- 78CA65430 should be kept the same: 78CA65430

My request is in the form of an XML:

```
<order>
<itemId>00012MD78009850</itemId>

</order>
```

I need to parse the value inside `itemId` and show `00012MD78009850` as `12MD78009850`.

I tried to use:

```
fn-bea:trim-left(fn:replace(data(order/itemId), '0' ,''))
```

but this replaced all zeros and got the incorrect result `12MD78985`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`fn:replace(data(order/itemId), '^0+', '')`

The `^` means process everything at the beginning of a string

The `0` is the character you would like to process (remove, trim)

The `+` one or more occurrences